# Twitter bootstrap apparently not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, asset-pipeline

I have a simple ROR project and I want to use Bootstrap-sass. I've added it to my Gemfile, run 
bundle install and have added "@import "bootstrap";" as the *very* first line of my css
file. As a quick test, I've cut and pasted an example of a couple of buttons with various styles.

They show up on the webpage as a couple of plain buttons.

How can I tell if bootstrap is actually getting loaded?

Update: Looking at the error console of the browser, I see the following message:
'The stylesheet localhost:3000/assets/bootstrap was not loaded because its MIME type, "application/javascript", is not "text/css"'

Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Comment: I think I have solved this. If I change the @import statement in my css file to "@import bootstrap.css" instead of "@import bootstrap", it seems to work.  Of course, this contravenes everything I've read about  installing bootstrap...

Answer (score 2):

I solved problem by renaming application.css to application.scss

First I think I did that, but apparently I didn't save the renamed file name.

Answer (score 0):

To start you can check your browser console's NET panel.  It should show a request for 'bootstrap.css'.  It sure sounds like it's not being pulled in.  This would be the first step in confirming.

Comment: Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-22 17:55:32 -0800    
    Served asset /application.js - 200 OK (0ms)                       
    Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-22 17:55:32 -0800  
    Served asset /jquery_ujs.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
    Started GET "/assets/bootstrap" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-22 17:55:32 -0800
    Served asset /bootstrap - 304 Not Modified (1ms)
    Started GET "/assets/logo.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-22 17:55:32 -0800
    Served asset /logo.png - 200 OK (0ms)

Comment: Can you post an html snippet?

Comment: <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Danger <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Warning <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <button class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Success <span class="caret"></span></button>

Comment: sorry about the lack of formatting. There's supposed to be a couple of button pulldowns.  Here's the URL I copied the example from: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/twitter-bootstrap.html

Comment: Mozilla console offers a clue? The stylesheet http://loalhost:3000/assets/bootstrap was not loaded because its MIME type, "application/javascript" is not "text/css".

Answer (score 0):

I remember the first time I worked with bootstrap it didn't work. It was because I didn't point the document root to the right place. Of course I usually check the document root because it a reoccurring problem for me, and now that I know I tend to make an error there I start there. I will say that taking time to look at the type of mistakes I make frequently has helped my growth.